# Local storage not working

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have this javascript which I need to run only once than local storage to save the state.The script changes login in logout. Even when page is refresh I don't want script to be executed :

```
var str=document.getElementById("tst").innerHTML;
var n=str.replace("Login","Logout");
document.getElementById("tst").innerHTML=n;
```

html :

```
<a href="login" title="log in" class="login_button" id="tst">Login</a></span>
```

I tried with this code but doesn't trigger the script at all now :

```
 var eventsFired = localStorage.getItem('fired');
 if (eventsFired != '1'){
 if (document.getElementById('tst')){
 var str=document.getElementById("tst").innerHTML;
 var n=str.replace("Login","Logout");
 document.getElementById("tst").innerHTML=n;
 localStorage.setItem('fired', '1'); 
 } }
```

Js fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/9t4Wb/4/

I even tried with cookies using jquery.cookies.js , same result :

```
var eventsFired = ($.cookie('eventsFired') != null)
? $.cookie('eventsFired')
: 0;

if (eventsFired == 0){

if (document.getElementById('tst'))
{
var str=document.getElementById("tst").innerHTML;
var n=str.replace("Login","Logout");
document.getElementById("tst").innerHTML=n;
eventsFired++;
$.cookie('eventsFired', eventsFired);
}}
```

Cookies Jsfiddle test  http://jsfiddle.net/JqxVj/5/

Comment: Nothing anymore. I remove it.

Comment: Your Fiddle seems to work fine for me (if you call `load`). Does your browser even support localStorage?

Comment: I remove it 'load'.I didn't know it does not support all browser.I use Chrome. I need best universal solution for my case.I understand the best thing is local storage. I tried with cookies too, I updated the post.

Comment: Chrome definitely supports localStorage. Also, your first JSFiddle works, all you have to do is place `load();` at the end of the Javascript code. If it's not working for you, you may have some kind of configuration problem. Also, you do realize that the jQuery cookie functionality is a plugin, right? It's not built into jQuery and won't work if you don't have the extra script.

Comment: I attached external source on jquery cookies jsfiddle page but don't work http://jsfiddle.net/JqxVj/5/.

Comment: My problem its still not solved. When page loads I need script to run once and Login to be changed in Logout - and remain that way with the help of local storage or cookies.

Comment: Open FireBug, In DOM tab, search "localstorage" keyword and view, how and when it change? also It's value

Answer (score 0):

If you need support for more than Chrome users, you can use [AmplifyJS](http://amplifyjs.com/)

It's let you use only one syntax on all browsers...

```
//Set value
amplify.store("myKey", myObject)

//Get value
amplify.store("myKey") // return myObject
```

You can also check [the documentation](http://amplifyjs.com/api/request/) and see the advantages of this plugin

Comment: Can you please add the external resources to fiddle and make it work for my case ?